# Derivative of a definite integral?

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I could not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Suppose

$$f(x)= \int_1^x \sin(t^2) \ dt$$
What is $f'(x)$?

I found $f'(x) = 0$. But it says this is not correct answer. Can someone please explain step by step?
Thanks

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = \int_1^x g(t) \ dt$. What is $f'(x)$ in general? *Hint:* Fundamental Theorem of Calculus!!

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a definite integral with respect to a variable which is the upper limit in the integral is always the integrand, substituting the variable for the dummy integration variable.  This is a form of the fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

Thus for any $a$,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x \sin(t^2) \, dt = \sin(x^2)
$$

Comment: Maybe you can extend to the case where the limits of integration are non-trivial functions of x?

Comment: Always the integrand *if* the integrand is continuous.

Comment: But you need to do the chain rule with limits of integration.

Answer (score 0):

For a generalization of Mark Fischler's answer above, you have :

$\frac {d}{dx} \int _{h(x)}^ {f(x)} g(t)dt =g(f(x))f'(x)-g(h(x))h'(x)$